# Need Help with InstallShield

Tags: c#, registry, installshield-2010

I'm using to Install Shield 2010 limited edition to create a installer of my application. I have never used it before. But now I need to create a installer and verify it by using Windows 7 client software logo toolkit. I have tested a .msi file using the toolkit and found some warnings. Among them 1 is

```
Applications are expected to create these registry entries DisplayName, InstallLocation, Publisher, UninstallString, VersionMajor*, and VersionMinor*.
```

Now I don't know how to write registry values using Install Shield. I also have a  **Code Signing Certificate**  but I don't know how to use it.

Any help on doing these will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Johnny

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the IS Limited edition here but have the Premier edition. For the Code Signing, go to the "Release" section, on the Signing tab, you can populate the certificate information (spc and pvk files). For the Registry items, go to Registry view, then right click then add these items.
DisplayName with a value of [ProductName]
InstallLocation with a value of [INSTALLDIR]
Publisher with a value of [COMPANYNAME]
Version with a value of [ProductVersion]

These might not be the same as for the Limited Edition. Hope this helps.